# place value in text box which has name in array format

Tags: jquery

In a page I have a number of text box with name in array format. I want to put a value 'test' in one of them when a function is executed or event is occured. But my jquery code puts value in all the textboxes. Also I cannot put ID to the textbox  as its framework generated.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="School[school_name]">
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="School[contact_person]">
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="School[test]">




$('input:text[name=School[school_name]]').val('test');
```

Thanks
Ab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input[name="School[school_name]"]').val('test');
```

​
Will do the magic for you. The syntax is: `$('tag[attribute="value"]')`

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around the name:

```
$('input:text[name="School[school_name]"]').val('test');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsfiddle that shows how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/2eYwQ/11/

Put the actual name in quotes.